Wordpress: My live page keeps showing my template instead of the actual content
I don't know if this is the right place to post this, but this problem is driving me crazy. I have spent a whole day not being able to continue with my project because of this issue. The solutions I have found online cant help me solve the problem
Basically, as you can see from the images, the content published is different from the content edited. It is obvious that the template values like color and font are being used but no matter what I do, the template keeps getting published



Hi have you try to save and publish the page? Also try to disable all of your plugins and see if this can fix the issue.
